# Selecting a database to use per specific APIView in the Django application

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Recently I added a second database to my Django application. I have prepared API a long time ago with the use of djangorestframework and now I would like to be able to choose which view should use which database.

I tried using [Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) however, I do not think it suits my need cause many of my views use the same models. I also hope to find a more elegant solution than just adding *.using()* method to every single query.

Comment: Database Router should be the way to go. Can you, please, add a bit more details (code) on how you tried to use it and what you're trying to archive

Comment: "many of my views use the same models" - do you mean same models with different DBs?